# Thermometer symbol in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating an app using Shiny and would like to include a thermometer plot, created using the `symbols()` function. I written the following code for my thermometer plot, and it works perfectly fine in the plot viewer in RStudio:

`symbols(0, thermometers = cbind(0.3, 9, 4.1/9), fg = 2, xlab = NA, ylab = NA, inches = 2.5, axes = F)`

However, when I try to use this in Shiny, nothing is displayed on the page. Here's my code:

`server = function(input, output, session) {
... (not needed for this plot)
}
ui = fluidPage(
tags$div(id="thermometer", style = "height:600px;", symbols(0, thermometers = cbind(0.3, 9, 4.1/9), fg = 2, xlab = NA, ylab = NA, inches = 2.5, axes = F))
)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)`

Inspecting the page shows that the div is being created, but the thermometer is not there. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make a plot appear in Shiny, you need to create an output serverside and then render it in the ui:

```
server = function(input, output, session) {
  #... (not needed for this plot)
  output$thermometer <- renderPlot({
    symbols(0, thermometers = cbind(0.3, 9, 4.1/9), fg = 2, xlab = NA, ylab = NA, inches = 2.5)
  })
}
ui = fluidPage(
  tags$div(id="thermometer", style = "height:600px;", plotOutput("thermometer"))
)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

EDIT: based on your comment an alternative way of plotting might be:

```
library(shiny)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  #... (not needed for this plot)
  output$thermometer <- renderPlot({
    symbols(0, thermometers = cbind(0.3, 1, 4.1/9), fg = 2, xlab = NA, ylab = NA, inches = 2.5, yaxt='n', xaxt='n', bty='n')
  })
}
ui = fluidPage(
  tags$div(id="thermometer", style = "height:600px;width:200px;margin:auto", plotOutput("thermometer"))
)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This removes the axes and box around the thermometer and makes it slightly more visible.

Comment: That worked, thanks. How do I "zoom in" on the thermometer so there isn't so much white space around it?

Comment: I don't quite know what you mean by "zoom in" but you can make the thermometer wider/narrower by changing the second argument in `c(0.3, 9, 4.1/9)`. I noticed that you removed the axes in your original question; you can do that by adding `yaxt='n', xaxt='n', bty='n'` to your `symbols` command.