# Horizontal thermometer bar in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I could create a thermometer type of chart from following code link:
[Thermometer symbol in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45615819/thermometer-symbol-in-shiny)

I want same chart in Horizontal way. Something like this.

[image]

1. Is it possible to do it?
2. If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a really simple horizontal bar chart with just one variable using GGPlot? You can play with the themes and axis limits so they are stripped away and the tick marks look like a thermometer. Here is a basic example taken from http://www.sthda.com:

```
df <- data.frame(dose=c("D0.5"),
            len=c(4.2))

p<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=dose, y=len)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
p

# Horizontal bar plot
p + coord_flip()+theme_classic()
```